# Set a variable and silence output in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, selenium, terminal, silent

I have this program on POWERSHELL:

```bsh
$ChromeOptions = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions 
$ChromeOptions.addargument('--kiosk-printing')
$driver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver($ChromeOptions)
```

This last line return in the terminal many informations ( ChromeDriver was started successfully. DevTools listening on etc ...).

**My problem is that I want to hide all of this message.**

I have already tried :

```bsh
1) ($driver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver($ChromeOptions))|Out-Null
2) $driver = (New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver($ChromeOptions))|Out-Null
3) $driver = [void] (New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver($ChromeOptions))
4) [void] ($driver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver($ChromeOptions))
5) $driver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver($ChromeOptions) -InformationVariable 'Ignore'
6) $driver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver($ChromeOptions) >$null
```

Any other ideas ? Thanks

Comment: Maybe Selenium writes to stderr. Try `2>&1 | out-null` that redirects stderr to stdout and both are sent to out-null.

Comment: You mean like that : $driver =  (New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver($ChromeOptions)  2>&1 | out-null) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will stop the console appearing entirely:

```
$ChromeService = [OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriverService]::CreateDefaultService()
$ChromeService.HideCommandPromptWindow = $true

$ChromeOptions = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions 
$ChromeOptions.addargument('--kiosk-printing')
$driver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver($ChromeService,$ChromeOptions)
```